# Something to catch exhaust particles made by bench grinder

Tags: bench

I am looking for something to attach to the exhaust of this bench grinder to catch the particles, especially the side with the grinding wheel.

It's making a big mess of particles.

It was a "flea market special" I bought about 40 years ago.

I am willing to make something if need be.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: try a magnet .... will not work on non-ferrous materials though .... maybe some sort of a tube that leads into a container  ... maybe made from canvas .... not sure how it would stand up to sparks

Comment: @jsotola Not sure how well a magnet would work as the wheel is rotating at 3450 rpm. The bag is a good idea.

Comment: What's the question? Fashion or procure some flame-retardant bags and zip-tie them on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a metal dryer hose connected to my grinder that drop into a bucket. I would not use a bag if you grind ferrous metals the hot sparks could catch the bag on fire, I used to have my grinder connected to a shop vacuum until I set the vacuum on fire. Having the larger pipes drop into a bucket works great, if I am really doing heavy grinding I sometimes put an inch of water in the bucket. A side note the metal filings and water really help my snow ball bush turn bright blue, a friend suggested using the steel dust and water on the snowball bush and it really helps almost like adding dye to the flowers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I went with:

[image]

It does not look pretty, but it does work.

Many thanks to all who helped. :-)